# wpf apply transforms when drawing drag adorner

Tags: wpf, transform, adorner

In our drag and drop implementation, we like the adorner to apply the adorned element's transform value.

The transform may apply to UIElements in Xaml like this:

```
<DockPanel.LayoutTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.75" ScaleY="0.75"/>
        <RotateTransform Angle="10" />
    </TransformGroup>
</DockPanel.LayoutTransform>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
...
```

This is how transforms are retrieved by summarizing the applied transforms of ancestor elements:

```
public static Transform GetAncestorTransforms(this DependencyObject descendant)
    {
        TransformGroup transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
        DependencyObject dObj = descendant;
        do
        {
            Visual visual = dObj as Visual;
            if (visual != null)
            {
                // determine the current transform by matrix determinants
                Transform t = VisualTreeHelper.GetTransform(visual);
                if (t != null)
                {
                    transformGroup.Children.Add(t);
                }
            }
            dObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dObj);
        }
        while (dObj != null);

        return transformGroup;
    }
```

The Adorner draws a round rectangle around the UIElement

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        var transform = (AdornedItem as DependencyObject).GetAncestorTransforms();
        if (transform != null)
        {
            drawingContext.PushTransform(transform);
        }
        Rect rect = new Rect(AdornedItem.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), AdornedElement), AdornedItem.RenderSize);
        drawingContext.DrawRoundedRectangle(null, new Pen(Foreground, 2), rect, 2, 2);
        if (transform != null)
        {
            drawingContext.Pop();
        }
    }
```

The code draws the adorner in the correct size (e.g. if it's a scale transform) or it rotates the adorner into the correct angle (if there's a skew/ rotatetransform) but anyway the rectangle is never around the adorned element. it's somewhere beside it. This looks like an offset problem ?

(Please note that the problem already occurs when theres just a single transform in the wohole visual tree. When there are more transforms, I'm aware that I might swap the order of the summarized transforms in GetAncestorTransforms().)

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:
The above code works, except one thing:
AdornedItem.TranslatePoint() calculates the starting point for the surrounding rectangle by (already) transformed UIElements. To not apply the transform twice, remove it from the point.

```
Point pos = AdornedItem.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), AdornedElement);
if (transform != null)
{
    pos = transform.Inverse.Transform(pos);
}
Rect rect = new Rect(pos, AdornedItem.RenderSize);
```